# Cannot find column 25 Exception coming

Tags: ms-access-2007, c#-3.0

I am creating one report where data exported from my access database to excel here. I'm not using any datagridview , when user click one checkbox appropriate report he can able to download for this I have written code but when I run this code its giving me Cannot find column 25, I don't know why its showing me this? 
In access table I have total 25 column :

```
string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
   string connectionString = null;

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            cnn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Billing WHERE Bill_No and Bill_Date is null order by FormNo desc";
            OleDbDataAdapter dscmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);
            cnn.Close();
 for (j = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].Caption; // Exception coming this line 
            }

            for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }
   System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            saveDlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveDlg.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls";
            saveDlg.FilterIndex = 0;
            saveDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
            saveDlg.Title = "Export Excel File To";
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded successfully...");
            xlApp.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer here i change my for loop

```
    for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].Caption;
            data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
        }
    }
```